# Origin of public defense of thesis

Tags: thesis, defense

An article on Martin Luther's "[Ninety-Five Theses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ninety-Five_Theses)" indicates that he posted the document on the church door according to "university custom". The reference included indicates various books. I recall hearing that this was the source of the public defense of some university degrees, but I cannot recall the source. Is this attribution correct or apocryphal?

Comment: That was more a church custom, to publish documents/announcements on the church door. The church near my home has a board on which e.g. church activities, upcoming christenings and so on, are regularly posted to the parishoners. Luther's theses became viral, reproduced by the (then very new) printing press, and what was a minor local complaint became the reformation. This has liitle (if any) relationship to thesis defenses.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/20542/19607

Comment: If it is according to university custom, then the practice must have existed before Luther.

Comment: Could you link to the article you read?

Comment: It wasn't an article. I recall hearing it somewhere, so that's why I asked the question.